# Trying to convert Latex to word using latex2rtf

Tags: msword, convert, latex2rtf

I'm trying to convert a `.tex` file into a word file using `latex2rtf`. In the terminal, I `cd` the folder the `.tex` file resides. The `.tex` file name is "linear algebra". I then wrote the following command on the terminal

```
mymac$ latex2rtf [-options] inputfile[linear_algebra.tex]
```

I get the following error message:

```
(Not set):1   Only a single file can be processed at a time
(Not set):1   Error!  Type "latex2rtf -h" for help
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like OP used literally:
`latex2rtf [-options] inputfile[linear_algebra.tex]`
and thus using so called standard placeholders as used in the documentation specifying:
`latex2rtf linear_algebra.tex` should solve the problem.